# Watching for DOM class changes using the Chome Dev Protocol

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I want to attach to an `inspectedWindow` in a Chrome Extension and detect specific classes that are added or removed to the DOM.

I am trying to use the [Chrome Dev Protocol API](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/DOM/) via the [chrome.debugger API](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/debugger/).

The issue is that events only seem to be fired for DOM nodes I have previously observed, and eventually the events stop firing for class changes (`DOM.setChildNodes`, `DOM.attributeModified`). Reading the DOM changes also seem to trigger more DOM.* events (I assume the dev protocols is sending me data about the nodes I recently observed).

I guess I would like something like `MutationObserver` for use over the debug protocol.

Is this possible?

Comment: As the documentation says "client receives DOM events only for the nodes that are known to the client".

Comment: @wOxxOm So do I need to visit every node in the tree to receive events for them?

Comment: Try DOMDebugger.setDOMBreakpoint on document's root node.